# Material Cardview - Children not getting clipped < API 28

Tags: android, android-cardview

When putting a nested scroll view inside a material card view with rounded corners and scrolling there is a bug where other material card views dont get clipped and there edges spill over the rounded corners. Text views and viewpager objects got there corners clipped fine. This bug appears on api 28 and below.

Does anyone know a work around for this?

[image: Not clipped API 28 <]

[image: Clipps API29 >]

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_workout_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="framework.presentation.workouts.WorkoutFragment"
>

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_workout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_workout_navigation"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_home" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    style="@style/cv_style_all_rounded"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/cv_margin_bottom"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/app_bar_workout"
    app:strokeColor="@color/dividerColor"
    app:strokeWidth="0.5dp">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        >

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/home_header_image"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/home_header" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/home_title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/header_margin_top"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/home_title"
                android:textSize="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline5"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_header_image" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/home_description"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/description_margin_top"
                android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/home_description"
                android:textSize="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/home_title" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider_home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                  android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/workout_intro_left_right_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/divider_margin_top"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/workout_intro_left_right_margin"
                android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/home_description" />

            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/quotesViewPager2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/start_end_padding"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/start_end_padding"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider_home" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFeaturedVideo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:text="@string/featured_video"
                android:textSize="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline6"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/quotesViewPager2" />

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/cvFeaturedVideo"
                style="@style/cv_style_home_layout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/start_end_padding"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/start_end_padding"
                android:clipChildren="true"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvFeaturedVideo">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/featuredThumbNail"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="210dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/featuredVideoTitle"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/featuredVideoTitle"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/youtubeIcon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/featuredThumbNail"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/youtube_logo_icon_150px" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Steps to recreate:

Constraint layout > Material card view (main container) > Nested Scroll View > Additional material card views (enough to scroll) & API 28 and below

Comment: Add your xml code.

Comment: Added some but its too big to spam all of it all you need is a Material cardview the size of the screen. Round the corner radius to 50dp. Stick a nested scroll view inside it. Then a bunch of nested material card views, enough to scroll inside the parent card view. Load the emulator up on API 28 or below and you will see the corners dont get clipped when scrolling.

Comment: Hi, why you make the inner `MaterialCardView` height as `match_parent`.. it seems that it can overlap with the outer `MaterialCardView`

Comment: @Zain I changed it to wrap content, it has no effect.

Comment: @HarisDautović Steps to recreate:

Constraint layout > Material card view (main container) > Nested Scroll View > Additional material card views (enough to scroll) & API 28 and below

Comment: I'm offering help but you need to create demo project on Github.  Thanks

Comment: API 28 is a strange threshold for this bug. Can you post your `cv_style_home_layout` style? Do you have multiple versions in v28 res directories? There may be some attribute causing this. Or, can you just use a normal View with elevation and a rounded rectangle for a background and use clipToOutline? CardView is not really necessary these days unless you're supporting pre-lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

In your Cardview, add the property in your xml:

```
cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this had no effect

Comment: Is this overlaping is showing on the preview page of android studio or also on the phone

Comment: Emulator and phone

Comment: Try using **androidx.cardview.widget.CardView** instead of **com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView** and add **app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"** as property

Comment: No effect unfortunately