# Android CardView rounded corner broken on Android API before 27

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I have cardview embedded in a parent CardView that has rounded corners (I'll name this parent CardView CV1). When I scroll the content of CV1, the child cardview overlaps CV1 and cancel the rounded corners of CV1 (as shown by the arrow in the video), on the other hand the TextView, ImageView, are well clipped and we always see the rounded corners of the map. See: threadvintage:
Note: This only happens on versions of Android API <= 27, on APIs> 28 everything is good.

Even when I add `app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"` and
`app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`

Code below

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
fibe:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
android:layout_margin="32dp">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        
        <include layout="@layout/item_list" />
        <include layout="@layout/item_list" />
        <include layout="@layout/item_list" />
        <include layout="@layout/item_list" />
        <include layout="@layout/item_list" />
        <include layout="@layout/item_list" />
        <include layout="@layout/item_list" />
        <include layout="@layout/item_list" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Videos are available here.

[Rendering on Tablet with Android API 24 : We have error here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LZoX9ZaIbXVEw0UmBo-pgZaJaeiPFBlH/view?usp=sharing)

[Rendering on Tablet with Android API 28 : Everything is good here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DVJs-Tkn9cOyPHUiOyWc_1q2RjIx2sbh/view?usp=sharing)

Update 1 : item_list layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="216dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        style="@style/RoundedCornersContentItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="148dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
 app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/content_item_badge_background"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/FlowPanelHeaderTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Very long title for my card" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65364988/6287910) the same problem?

Comment: @Cheticamp  it is similar. In my case, I'm not using the MaterialCardView

Comment: _MaterialCardview_ extends _CardView_, so I think that it is probably the same problem. Also [this  bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176079159) seems to identify it as well. Can you post the XML for the item_list layout?

Comment: @Cheticamp see the ```item_list``` layout in the code update..

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely broken on API 27 and below. It seems to be a known problem, but I don't see any fixes for it.

The following layout, slightly modified from your layouts, will reproduce the problem if any want to take a look.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="32dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/item_list" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_list" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_list" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_list" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_list" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_list" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_list" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_list" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**item_list.xml**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="32dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/item_list" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_list" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_list" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_list" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_list" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_list" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_list" />

            <include layout="@layout/item_list" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Here is a demo on an API 27 emulator:

[image]

I can't say exactly what the issue is and it is odd that the nested *CardView* overlays the corners of the outer *CardView* while the *TextView* respect those corners.

In lieu of an outright fix, a work-around would be to create a custom *CardView* that does it's own corner clipping. Here is such a custom view:

**MyCardView.kt**

class MyCardView @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : CardView(context, attrs) {

```
    private lateinit var mRectF: RectF
    private val mPath = Path()
    private var mCornerRadius = 0f

    init {
        val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.CardView, 0,
            R.style.CardView
        )
        mCornerRadius = a.getDimension(androidx.cardview.R.styleable.CardView_cardCornerRadius, 0f)
        a.recycle()
    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        mRectF = RectF(0f, 0f, w.toFloat(), h.toFloat())
        resetPath()
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            canvas.withClip(mPath) {
                super.draw(canvas)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun resetPath() {
        mPath.apply {
            reset()
            addRoundRect(mRectF, mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW)
            close()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the demo with the custom *CardView* on the same API 27 emulator:

[image]